# A continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if it maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

Tags: real-analysis

A continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if it maps
Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

is the above statement is true?

I guess it is not true but can't find any counterexample.

Comment: No, $f(x)=x^2$ is a counterexample, and I think there might be a duplicate question.  However, I apologize for my hasty vote to close, because I voted to close as duplicate of the following question which is not a duplicate (without reading carefully): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40676/

Comment: (Pete L. Clark's answer at the linked question points out why every continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no as explained by Jonas Meyer and every continuous function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ has this property:

If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence then $m\leq x_n \leq M, \ \ \forall \ n\in\mathbb N$ for some $m<M$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[m,M]$ the result follows.

So $f(x)=x^2$ (or any continuous not uniformly continuous function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$) is a counterexample.

Comment: Alternatively, because every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ converges, there exists $x$ such that $x_n\to x$, and by continuity $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  Since $(f(x_n))_n$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Right, that is better.

Comment: @JonasMeyer you were talking about the proof of converse in the comment, right?

Comment: @Maneesh: No, the comment is about an alternative proof that every continuous $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: sorry! actually, I didn't see the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Question was this no?A continuous function $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous if it maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @JonasMeyer your comment was  cauchy sequence under continuous map is a cauchy sequence.Right?

Comment: sorry! I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Now I understood. Thank you very much :).